# Unit test for coverting comma separated string of ints to int array

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to this, so really don't know if i'm doing this right.
The code I want to test is:

```
public int[] IntArray(string text)
{
    return text.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToArray();
}
```

The test I already have is not complete, so hoping someone can help:

```
 [TestClass]
 public class ContextHelperTests
 {
     public ContextHelper CreateTarget()
     {
       var context = new ContextHelper();        
     }

     return new ContextHelper();
 }

 [TestMethod]
 public void TestContextHelper()
 {
     // Arrange
     var expectedResult = 12,3;
 }

 // Act
 var values = context.Split(',');
 int actualResult = values.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

 // Assert
 Assert.That(actualResult, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the test is not cpmplete"?

Comment: What is your question? The unit test code you show is not valid c#.

Comment: I just want to test the code. I've looked at some examples and come up with the test code above

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  Is it that it doesn't compile? That the test code doesn't use the actual implementation?  That the test gives the wrong result?

Comment: That the test code doesn't use the actual implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want in your test code to duplicate all your source code logic.. that makes no sense. Instead because you know what the input is and know how your output should be then just specify it - and then make sure they are equal

Your test class should look something along these lines:

```
[TestClass]
public class ContextHelperTests
{
    private SomeClassWithThatMethod _instance;

    private string _inputText = "123 , 324 , 4";
    private int[] _expectedOutput = new int[] {123, 324, 4};

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _instance = new SomeClassWithThatMethod();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IntArray_ValidInput_3ItemsInOutput()
    {
        var response = _instance.IntArray(_inputText);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(response, _expectedOutput);
    }
}
```

*And just for the fun of it - check out a library called FluentAssertions - Great extension methods to make all the `Assert.` part much more readable and cleaner*

Comment: Thank you.If I use Assert.That(actualResult, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult)) or the one you describe I get the error that assert does not contain a definition for 'that'.

Comment: @Shan's - ya - I was just coping the assertion that you had but here is a quick edit (still I prefer fluentAssertion but that is personal opinion)

Answer (score 3):

When you implement a test, you won't duplicate the code you want to test, but **you test the whole code**.

For example, if you want to test your `IntArray` method, you just need to call it and do some assertions to be sure that it's working as you expect:

```
var expectedResult = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = whatever.IntArray("1,2,3");

Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Length);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[0], result[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[1], result[1]);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[2], result[2]);
```